# PythonOperator with python_callable set gets executed constantly

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from workflow.task import some_task

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['jimin.park1@aig.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0)
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('JiminTest', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *', catchup=False)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Task1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=some_task,
    dag=dag
)
```

The actual some_task itself simply appends timestamp to some file. As you can see in the dag config file, the task itself is configured to run every 1 min.

```
def some_task(ds, **kwargs):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(current_time + '\n')
```

I simply tail -f the output file and started up the webserver without the scheduler running. This function was being called and things were being appended to the file when webserver starts up. When I start up the scheduler, on each execution loop, the file gets appended.

What I want is for the function to be executed on every minute as intended, not every execution loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheduler will run each DAG file every scheduler loop, including all import statements.

Is there anything running code in the file from where you are importing the function?

Comment: Amazing. That was the problem. There was the method call some where in the imported py file... I must have left it there for testing purposes. Thank you for pointing this out. Didn't know import was being called on every scheduler loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the `scheduler_heartbeat_sec` config parameter in your config file. For your case it should be smaller than 60 seconds.

If you want the scheduler not to cahtchup previous runs set `catchup_by_default`to False (I am not sure if this relevant to your question though).

Please indicate which Apache Airflow version are you using